# How to recognized which request in the response in the same delegate method with https.(iOS)

Tags: ios, ssl, https, delegates

I have multi request in the same page in different button.

I implement the https connection delegate(NSURLSessionDataDelegate).

So we have

```
 -(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:     (NSURLSessionDataTask*)dataTask didReceiveResponse:(nonnull NSURLResponse      *)response completionHandler:(nonnull void (^)     (NSURLSessionResponseDisposition))completionHandler{
      completionHandler(NSURLSessionResponseAllow);
  }
```

and

```
 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session dataTask:(NSURLSessionDataTask *)dataTask didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
 {

     NSString* result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     NSLog(@"result:%@",result);

 }

 - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
 {
 }
```

delegate method.

I create the connection with NSURLSession.

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
sessionConfig.TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol1;

 NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
 NSURL* url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"MY_DIFFERENT_PATH"];
 NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
 NSString* params = @"myParams";
 NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request];
```

If I have multi different request the the server in https.

How to recognized which connect in the same response delegate method?

thank you very much.

Comment: An option could be to extend NSURLSessionDataTask by adding an enum to represent your different tasks and check it inside your delegate

Comment: I am trying to add the taskIdentifier. task.taskIdentifier = 1; But it will show taskIdentifier is readonly property.